# How to stop Siri from playing undownloaded purchased songs

Tags: iphone, siri

Here is an interesting one:

1. I have 264 purchased songs downloaded on my iPhone
2. If I go "Songs > Shuffle" it goes 1 of 264
3. If I go "Siri > Play songs shuffled" it goes 1 of 456

So basically, if I use Siri, it keeps shuffling through every song I have purchased rather than just the ones that have been downloaded onto my iPhone.

I have already tried:

1. Settings > Music > Show All Music Off
2. Settings > iTunes & App Store > Show all music off + Automatic downloads music off
3. Settings > Usage > Music delete + iTune sync to put back only the songs I wanted

How do I stop this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know about a better solution than logging out of the Apple Store. It will prevent Siri from accessing your purchased songs library from there.

Comment: Clever solution! After googling many users had the same issue but no one had a solution.